# conditioning issue to locate a group

Tags: regex, regex-group

How can I make this regex

```
(\w|[-zàâçéèêëîïôûùüÿñæœ ])* :((\w|[-zàâçéèêëîïôûùüÿñæœ ])*, [\w]*){1}
```

separate both tests at the same time to:

test :

```
Gérant : Jean-Pierre LEVENDEAIN, Associé : Toumiat, Farid
Gérant : Jean-Pierre, LEVENDEAIN, Associé : Toumiat, Farid
```

Update:

The question is I need 1 regex expression that evaluates both lines and produces these groups:

first case:

- Gérant : Jean-Pierre LEVENDEAIN,
- Associé : Toumiat, Farid

second case:

- Gérant : Jean-Pierre, LEVENDEAIN
- Associé : Toumiat, Farid

The problem I found, is sometimes I have text with A: B, C, or A: B
and I need both to be matched as a group

Update:

There is a test case I didn't consider

> Président : Chateau, Nathalie, nom d'usage : Rudzinski, Directeur
> général : Montmirel, Joëlle, nom d'usage : Ciocco, Directeur général
> délégué : Rudzinski, Stéphane

Comment: FYI `{1}` is always redundant. A pattern is always matched 1 time unless it's quantified otherwise.

Comment: Why are you using `|`? You can just put `\w` inside the `[...]`

Comment: I don't understand the question. If you use a function that finds all matches, each match will include all its capture groups. The details depend on the language you're using.

Comment: Your regexp won't include `Toumiat, Farad` in the result. It only matches a single `:`

Comment: I have updated my post, check the expected results for both test cases, as i need 1 regex expression to evaluate them (they are french words btw)

Comment: Try `(\S+)\s*:\s*(.*?)(?=\s*\S+\s+:|$)`, see https://regex101.com/r/Hqx7w7/1. Does it work as expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```js
([^,\s][^,]*)\s*:\s*(.*?)(?=[^,]*:|$)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Hqx7w7/2). *Details*:

- `([^,\s][^,]*)` - Group 1: a char other than a comma and whitespace and then zero or more non-comma chars
- `\s*:\s*` -  a colon enclosed with zero or more whitespaces
- `(.*?)` - Group 2: any zero or more chars other than line break chars as few as possible
- `(?=[^,]*:|$)` - a positive lookahead that matches a location that is immediately followed with

  - `[^,]*:` - zero or more non-commas and then a `:` char
  - `|` - or
  - `$` - end of string.

JavaScript demo:

```js
const re = /([^,\s][^,\n]*)\s*:\s*(.*?)(?=[^,\n]*:|$)/gm
const text = `Gérant : Jean-Pierre LEVENDEAIN, Associé : Toumiat, Farid
Gérant : Jean-Pierre, LEVENDEAIN, Associé : Toumiat, Farid
Président : Chateau, Nathalie, nom d'usage : Rudzinski, Directeur général : Montmirel, Joëlle, nom d'usage : Ciocco, Directeur général délégué : Rudzinski, Stéphane.`
const matches = Array.from(text.matchAll(re), x => [x[1].trim(), x[2].trim()])
for (const x of matches) {
  console.log(x)
}
```

Comment: we forgot a test case

Président : Chateau, Nathalie, nom d'usage : Rudzinski, Directeur général : Montmirel, Joëlle, nom d'usage : Ciocco, Directeur général délégué : Rudzinski, Stéphane.

nom d'usage is not considered as a single block

Comment: @DrissNajih What is your programming language?

Comment: i use javascript

Comment: it's not matching anything

Comment: @DrissNajih See https://regex101.com/r/Hqx7w7/3 and I added a regex demo into the answer.

Comment: YES working like a charm

Comment: Thank you and i'm sorry! Im new here hihi